# Can't able to display the records of Contacts column in PageBlockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce

Controller :

```
public class SOQL_ParentChildLookup {
    public List<Account> accs {get;set;}
    public Boolean flag1 {get;set;}
    public Boolean flag2 {get;set;}
    public void standardObjectStandardLkup(){
        flag1=true;
        flag2=false;
        accs = [select name,industry, (select lastName,firstName from Contacts) from Account];
    }
     public void standardObjectCustomLkup(){
         flag1=false;
         flag2=true;
        accs = [select name,industry, (select lastName,firstName from CustomContacts__r) from Account];
    }
}
```

Visualforce Page :

```
<apex:page controller="SOQL_ParentChildLookup">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="SOQL ParentChildLookup">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton value="Standard Lookup" action="{!standardObjectStandardLkup}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Custom Lookup" action="{!standardObjectCustomLkup}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accs}" var="a" rendered="{!flag1}">
                <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!a.industry}"/>       
                <apex:column headerValue="Contacts"/>
                <apex:repeat value="{!a.Contacts}" var="b">
                    {!b.lastName}.{!b.firstName} <br/>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accs}" var="a" rendered="{!flag2}">
                <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!a.industry}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Contacts"/>
                <apex:repeat value="{!a.CustomContacts__r}" var="c">
                    {!c.lastName}.{!c.firstName} <br/>
                </apex:repeat>
                 </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the contacts between column tag.

```
<apex:column headerValue="Contacts">
    <apex:repeat value="{!a.CustomContacts__r}" var="c">
        {!c.lastName}.{!c.firstName} <br/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:column>
```